# why dropdown selection never fire in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a search page, called : search.ascx.cs and search.ascx; when users search, it will call dosearch() and inside this it calls to ReloadDetails() and DataBind_Results() functions in searchDatagrid.ascx.cs .

Now, I created a dropdown menu inside that searchDatagrid.ascx

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="200px"  
autopostback="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1sel">
</asp:DropDownList>
</br>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
```

but it will have error "Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page.."
so I cut this part:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

and move it to search.ascx file.
For the dropdown option I successfully populated it in searchDatagrid.ascx.cs file:

```
foreach (var standart in companies1.Select(c => c.compnStandards1).Distinct())
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(standart));
}
```

and to fire the action when user choose an option in dropdown menu I make this test function in searchDatagrid.ascx.cs file also:

```
public void DropDownList1sel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "http://www.google.com";
    string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
}
```

Now, I can see the dropdown display well! The problem is when I click to one option, it never fire the function to open the window. I know that it will not go to that function. So why is that so ? I am really confuse here!

Comment: Are you using `MasterPages`? If so, look for a `ScriptManager` in one of them.

Comment: This code I modifying some one's old code. So I don't know how to know they use master page or not and where to look for that ?

Comment: @fubo: could you explain how to do so, the trigger thing ?

Comment: You can look at the `Page` header bit. Or a simple search for `MasterPage`.

Comment: Please add the code where you populate the dropdown, it' shouldn't be repopulated on the postback I think, because it won't trigger OnSelectedIndexChanged I suppose

Comment: On the postback you mean after clicking one option in dropdown menu ? After clicking it, the page become blank, the dropdown disappear also. I populate the dropdown by foreach loop above, it is inside private void DataBind_Results() function, quite long code, which part you want me to add ?

Comment: @user1314404. When debugging, does it trigger the event handler "DropDownList1sel" ?

Comment: No, it doesn't ! I don't know why so.

Comment: @user1314404, That 's because you repopulate DropDownList1sel with data on PostBack I suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it is not because the dropdown list not calling the codebehind but because the variable in the codebehind was empty then it shows no result which make I think that it is not firing. To fix it just make the variable global (public static) and the value will be stored after changing in each method.

Answer (score 0):

Take away updatepanel and check if it works then. If so then start debug session in the browser. Probably js error preventing the postback. Test Updatemode=conditional on the updatepanel to.

Comment: I took it away but there is no difference. What else I can try ?

Comment: Also test <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1"
                                 UpdateMode="Conditional"
                                 runat="server"> but the same.

Answer (score 0):

When using `UpdatePanel` you have to use this instead:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    updatePanel                 // tells the page this control is updating the script
    , updatePanel.GetType()     // tells the type of the control updating
    , Guid.NewGuid().ToString() // generates a unique key every request,
                                // so always update the script
    , s
    , true);
```

Comment: is it equivalent to this : ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "newWindow", s,true); ?